# Is it mandatory to use Couchbase at both client and server end for seamless sync operations?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I want to know  how to sync Couchbase with other Databases seamlessly? Can we use different databases with Couchbase in the same project?

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't specified which databases you have in mind, I will give you a broad answer:

**Mobile:** Couchbase can be sync with Couchbase Lite (https://www.couchbase.com/products/lite) via Sync Gateway - the middleware between cblite and Couchbase Server. Sync Gateway is mandatory in this case for security reasons, as you should not simply expose your database on the web.

- Xamarin: https://blog.couchbase.com/synchronized-drawing-apps-with-couchbase-mobile/
- Android: https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/java-android.html
- Swift: https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/swift.html
- Java: https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/java-platform.html
- Others: https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/index.html

Couchbase Lite 1.x could also be sync with PouchDB, but we dropped this support on Couchbase Lite 2.x as we rewrote the whole thing and this is a feature yet to come.

**Server:** One of the most common ways to sync Couchbase Server with another database is through the Kafka Connector https://docs.couchbase.com/kafka-connector/current/index.html